# How to install Android Studio on a pc without internet connection?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I'd like to install Android Studio in pc which has no internet connection.

- I have already downloaded the JDK-7 and the Android Studio using
  another laptop.
- I have copied the both setup files and successfully installed JDK-7.
- Now when i'm running android-studio setup , it requires internet
  connection.(step screenshot attached)

Is there any way to skip this step by downloading any other setup(exe) file ?
[image]

After downloading all the required files (Development Studio, SDK and Platform), then when you run the Android Development Studio installation, it does not give me an option to select the previously downloaded components, but instead just goes ahead and attempts to download from the internet.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: You need an internet connection to download the sdk tools; I don't quite get what you are asking here

Comment: So, you'd like to say download JDK, SDK and AS on another computer and then bring it to this one which is offline and install it there?

Comment: I download JDK, SDK and android studio but to install I want to install offline

Comment: If you have everything downloaded then you don't need to be online to install it. What exactly is the problem/error you are having?

Comment: the first step I do it install jdk and then android studio and the third step the android studio install sdk "directly"  if it connect with internet but if I haven't internet android studio doesn't install the SDK I need a way to install it without internet how ???

Comment: @lena, What is the simulation that you used to run android on pc?

Answer (score 9):

There are 3 main components to a working Android development setup:

1. **JDK** (Java Development Kit)   Android
2. **SDK** (Android SoftwareDevelopment Kit)
3. **IDE** (Integrated Development Environment)

First download all three:
Download standalone [JDK installer from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), and [Android SDK and Android Studio from here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other).

Now, **move the files to whichever machine you want** to install your development environment on and **install all of them**.

The SDK comes packed with only the latest platform (21 at the time of writing) so if you need to use others, you will need to download them separately:

**Platforms**
• [android-1.1_r1-macosx](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-1.1_r1-macosx.zip)

• [android-1.1_r1-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-1.1_r1-linux.zip)

• [android-1.5_r04-windows](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-1.5_r04-windows.zip)

• [android-1.5_r04-macosx](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-1.5_r04-macosx.zip)

• [android-1.5_r04-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-1.5_r04-linux.zip)

• [android-1.6_r03-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-1.6_r03-linux.zip)

• [android-1.6_r03-macosx](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-1.6_r03-macosx.zip)

• [android-1.6_r03-windows](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-1.6_r03-windows.zip)

• [android-2.0_r01-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.0_r01-linux.zip)

• [android-2.0_r01-macosx](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.0_r01-macosx.zip)

• [android-2.0_r01-windows](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.0_r01-windows.zip)

• [android-2.0.1_r01-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.0.1_r01-linux.zip)

• [android-2.0.1_r01-macosx](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.0.1_r01-macosx.zip)

• [android-2.0.1_r01-windows](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.0.1_r01-windows.zip)

• [android-2.1_r03-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.1_r03-linux.zip)

• [android-2.2_r03-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.2_r03-linux.zip)

• [android-2.3.1_r02-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.3.1_r02-linux.zip)

• [android-2.3.3_r02-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.3.3_r02-linux.zip)

• [android-3.0_r02-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-3.0_r02-linux.zip)

• [android-3.1_r03-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-3.1_r03-linux.zip)

• [android-3.2_r01-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-3.2_r01-linux.zip)

**Samples**
• [samples-2.1_r01-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-2.1_r01-linux.zip)

• [samples-2.2_r01-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-2.2_r01-linux.zip)

• [samples-2.3_r01-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-2.3_r01-linux.zip)

• [samples-2.3.3_r01-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-2.3.3_r01-linux.zip)

• [samples-3.0_r01-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-3.0_r01-linux.zip)

• [samples-3.1_r01-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-3.1_r01-linux.zip)

• [samples-3.2_r01-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-3.2_r01-linux.zip)

• [samples-14_r02](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-14_r02.zip)

• [samples-15_r02](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-15_r02.zip)

• [samples-16_r01](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-16_r01.zip)

• [samples-17_r01](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-17_r01.zip)

• [samples-18_r01](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-18_r01.zip)

**Build Tools**
• [build-tools_r17-windows](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r17-windows.zip)

• [build-tools_r17-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r17-linux.zip)

• [build-tools_r17-macosx](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r17-macosx.zip)

• [build-tools_r18.0.1-windows](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r18.0.1-windows.zip)

• [build-tools_r18.0.1-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r18.0.1-linux.zip)

• [build-tools_r18.0.1-macosx](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r18.0.1-macosx.zip)

• [build-tools_r18.1-windows](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r18.1-windows.zip)

• [build-tools_r18.1-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r18.1-linux.zip)

• [build-tools_r18.1-macosx](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r18.1-macosx.zip)

• [build-tools_r18.1.1-windows](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r18.1.1-windows.zip)

• [build-tools_r18.1.1-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r18.1.1-linux.zip)

• [build-tools_r18.1.1-macosx](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r18.1.1-macosx.zip)

• [build-tools_r19-windows](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r19-windows.zip)

• [build-tools_r19-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r19-linux.zip)

• [build-tools_r19-macosx](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r19-macosx.zip)

• [build-tools_r19.0.1-windows](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r19.0.1-windows.zip)

• [build-tools_r19.0.1-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r19.0.1-linux.zip)

• [build-tools_r19.0.1-macosx](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r19.0.1-macosx.zip)

• [build-tools_r19.0.2-windows](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r19.0.2-windows.zip)

• [build-tools_r19.0.2-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r19.0.2-linux.zip)

• [build-tools_r19.0.2-macosx](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r19.0.2-macosx.zip)

• [build-tools_r19.0.3-windows](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r19.0.3-windows.zip)

• [build-tools_r19.0.3-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r19.0.3-linux.zip)

• [build-tools_r19.0.3-macosx](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r19.0.3-macosx.zip)

• [build-tools_r19.1-windows](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r19.1-windows.zip)

• [build-tools_r19.1-linux](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r19.1-linux.zip)

• [build-tools_r19.1-macosx](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r19.1-macosx.zip)

**Sources**
• [sources-14_r01](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sources-14_r01.zip)

• [sources-15_r02](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sources-15_r02.zip)

• [sources-16_r02](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sources-16_r02.zip)

• [sources-17_r01](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sources-17_r01.zip)

• [sources-18_r01](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sources-18_r01.zip)

• [sources-19_r02](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sources-19_r02.zip)

Hope it helps.

Comment: how to install these package after downloading  ?