# installing android development tool

Tags: android, sdk

I have few question regardig android development kit.
I have downloaded the android developemtn kit from android site(google).I have installed the appropriate java (jdk) too.
When the installation was completed and the android development kit (ide) started :

1) First it asked for the proxy setting.The system where i installed the adk has no internet connection.Is is compulsory that the environment should have environment ?

2) Then i installed it in the system with internet access, after installation is started downloading the sdk.I wonder the skd is available in user/appdata then why is it downloading?
Shouldn't it take the sdk from the hard drive?

3) I went through several site for installing adk but no one dealed with the problem.Can any one help he to get rid of it.

I am having problme installing adk even after i have all the required components.
Is there someone giving detail on installing adk in windows?

Comment: All your answers can be found 


  [Here]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609115/how-to-install-android-studio-on-a-pc-without-internet-connection

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is the Recommended SDK for android development. Just download and install the Android Studio it will automatically download required files when you run it first time.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html

[**Update1**]

I couldn't find a proper way to do it. But you can do it. Let it start the initial download and once it started just cancel it by closing the window.

[image]

Now the download is cancelled. Click 'Finish' on next step.

[image]

In the next screen You can configure your SDK via `Configure > Project Defaults > Project Structure > SDKs`

[image]

Comment: yes its true after installation of android development tool (studio) in the first run it start downloading the sdk but i have already download it.What i want is simply map the sdk(already downloaded one) during the first run.Isn't is possible ?